# Including a notes column in an excel query

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to include a notes column next to a query from an incident management site and to also make sure that the header row stays the same size.

Here's what I have so far. When I run it, it includes the notes in the table so they will refresh and follow the different incident statuses without losing the notes, but the way I wrote it doesn't allow for new rows.

The header row sizing isn't super essential, but that isn't working at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub IncludeNotes()
'
' IncludeNotes Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query").Resize Range("$A$1:$X$506")
    Range("Table_query[[#Headers],[ID]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 65

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code refactored to expand the ListObject by one column, and not change the number of rows.  Also tidies up the code, removing the unnecessary Selects etc, and resizes the header row regardless of what row it's on

```
Sub IncludeNotes()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query")
    lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(, lo.Range.Columns.Count + 1)
    lo.HeaderRowRange.RowHeight = 65
End Sub
```